# Python WSGI script with MySQL query shows old results

Tags: mysql, python-3.6, mod-wsgi, apache2.4

I have set up a Python WSGI script that queries a MySQL database. This works correctly the first time. However, after I update the MySQL data, the script returns the old data instead of the new, and I'm not sure why. My Apache configuration doesn't have caching enabled and neither does the MySQL database. If I run the python file directly I get the new MySQL data. If i restart Apache then i also get the new MySQL data. I think I'm missing something simple. Any tips?

Comment: "However, after I update the MySQL data, the script returns the old data instead of the new, and I'm not sure why" " If i restart Apache then i also get the new MySQL data. I think I'm missing something simple. Any tips?" Sounds like WSGI has caching?.. The problem with caching how to notify the application cache is outdated vs the database version/data... MySQL does not really have a method for that native, PostgreSQL on the other hand has `NOTIFY/LISTEN` statementsi believe for MySQL there was a UDF (User-Defined Function) that simulated that..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Sounds interesting. Do you know of a way to force the WSGI script to always query the data again? The query load will be low so I have no use for caching anything.